# Challenging Loop issue in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code, but have not been able to get it to loop the way that I would like it to.

Every 600 cells my data set changes to a new day, and I would like to loop it so that the proper calculations occur. In between the 600 cell blocks, there are 15 data subsets that all vary in length. The `DO` however follow the same pattern, which is that there is a blank and then 2 useless title cells that do not need to be calculated.

How can I loop this code so that it will run through the 15 subsets and then repeat every 600 cells? Thank you.

```
 Sub SelectandCount()
    Dim Top As Double
    Dim Bottom As Double
    Dim Ratio As Double
    Dim count As Integer

    For count = 0 To 600

    N = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Range("C4:C" & N).Select

    Rownum = Selection.Rows.count

    NumberofRows = Rownum * 0.2
    AdjustedNumberofRows = Round(NumberofRows)

    Sheet1.Range("E1").Value = Array(" As Number")
    Worksheets(1).Range("E2").Value = AdjustedNumberofRows

    ActiveCell.Resize(AdjustedNumberofRows, 1).Select

    Topsum = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Selection)
    Top = (Topsum / AdjustedNumberofRows)
    Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = Array("Top")
    Worksheets(1).Range("F2").Value = Top

    Range("C3").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1 - AdjustedNumberofRows).Resize(AdjustedNumberofRows).Select

    Bottomsum = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Selection)
    Bottom = (Bottomsum / AdjustedNumberofRows)

    Sheet1.Range("G1").Value = Array("Bottom")
    Worksheets(1).Range("G2").Value = Bottom

    MetricRatio = (Top / Bottom)
    Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = Array("Ratio")
    Worksheets(1).Range("H2").Value = Ratio
    Next
   'ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Resize(AdjustedNumberofRows).Select

    MsgBox ("Done")

    End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a counter that resets every 15 rows, or you could find an identifier in your data that could control a trigger. I often do that with date changes, storing the current date as a string variable and checking it against data add I loop through it. If there's a change, I store the new date and continue on.

Comment: *there are 15 data subsets that all vary in length*...this will be a challenge without some kind of indicator. Most likely you would need conditional `if/then` or `select/case` inside a loop. Please post some kind of mock/sample  data for reproducible example.

Comment: the indicators differ, but they are either ( A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I, J, or K). It should be noted that each set has all of these and then it restarts. I think the most logical approach would be to scan for these and stop at a particular row number. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- datasets are in column C
- datasets follow one another and each one is exactly 600 rows wide
- datasubsets are part of datasets
- a datasubset begin with an empty cell and doesn't any empty cells after that (i.e.: the next empty cell would be the one at the beginning of the next subset)
- a datasubset relevant data begin from its 4th row (the first row is empty, the 2nd and the 2rd are titles)

then you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectandCount()

Dim AdjustedNumberofRows As Long, iDataSet As Long, iData As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dataSetIniCell As Range, dataSubSetIniCell As Range, dataSubSetRng As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

iData = -1
Set dataSetIniCell = sht.Cells(1, 3)
Do While Not IsEmpty(dataSetIniCell.Offset(1))

    Call WriteHeaders(iDataSet, iData, sht.Range("E1:H1"))

    Set dataSubSetIniCell = dataSetIniCell
    Do While Not IsEmpty(dataSubSetIniCell.Offset(1)) And dataSubSetIniCell.Row - dataSetIniCell.Row < 600

        iData = iData + 1
        Set dataSubSetRng = sht.Range(dataSubSetIniCell.Offset(3), dataSubSetIniCell.Offset(3).End(xlDown))

        AdjustedNumberofRows = Round(dataSubSetRng.Rows.count * 0.2)

        sht.Range("E1:G1").Offset(iData) = Array(AdjustedNumberofRows, _
                                                 Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dataSubSetRng.Resize(AdjustedNumberofRows)) / AdjustedNumberofRows, _
                                                 Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dataSubSetRng.Offset(dataSubSetRng.Rows.count - AdjustedNumberofRows).Resize(AdjustedNumberofRows)) / AdjustedNumberofRows)

        sht.Range("H1").Offset(iData) = sht.Range("F1").Offset(iData) / sht.Range("G1").Offset(iData)

        Set dataSubSetIniCell = dataSubSetIniCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown).Offset(1)
    Loop

    Set dataSetIniCell = dataSetIniCell.Offset(600)

Loop

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub


Sub WriteHeaders(iDataSet As Long, iData As Long, refRng As Range)

iDataSet = iDataSet + 1
refRng.Resize(, 1).Offset(iData + 1).Value = "DataSet " & iDataSet
refRng.Offset(iData + 2).Value = Array(" As Number", "Top", "Bottom", "Ratio")
iData = iData + 2

End Sub
```